# Get Cron to run based on User Input

Tags: python, cron

I have a flask app that schedules tasks (python scripts) to run. I've done some searching and I believe using cron is the best solution to schedule these tasks. However, the time these tasks runs depends on user input. A user can input the date they want the script to start running along with the cadence (daily, weekly, etc..)

I'm stuck on how I can get this input and get cron to run these scripts based on this information. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

A standard pattern for this functionality is to create a bootstrap cron job that runs every minute; its purpose is to check your database for tasks to run at a certain time.

In many cases, the every-minute cron job executes almost immediately. When it finds a job to run (based on a preset-schedule or user input stored in the database) it will execute the desired task.

This functionality is provided by a number of frameworks; consider using one such as the PHP-based [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) as a guide.